# A single pod is in ContainerCreating Phase and others are in Running Phase

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

What does it means, if a single pod is in ContainerCreating Phase and others are in Running Phase, of a particular service? Is my service down or anything I need to worry about?

Didn't found anything reliable

Comment: Please check events in that namespace or describing the pod which will give clue on what is going wrong

Comment: it may indicate that you have a misconfiguration. You can get a high level overview by using `kubectl describe` on the pod. Many times you will find the issue. For example, it may wait for a volume, or it cannot be scheduled due to taints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it means, if a single pod is in **ContainerCreating** Phase and
> others are in Running Phase, of a particular service?

Not particular **service**, focus on **deployment** here. if you single POD is in **ContainerCreating** Phase others are in **Running** and Also **Ready 1/1** your service is **not** down, it's up & running as a service forward request to only **Ready** one.

Service will only route to traffic those are **Ready 1/1** doesn't matter about the other staus **containerCreating**, **Running**, **imagepullbackoff**

Even if your PODs are **Running** but **not** **Ready 1/1** you can consider your service as **down**.

**Extra**

Check leveraging the [Readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use `kubectl describe pod NAME` to check more details about the pod.